# Aginity for Netezza Create Temp Table from external xlsx file using ODBC

Tags: sql, odbc, temp-tables, netezza, import-from-excel

In Aginity Workbench for Netezza, I am trying to create a temp table from a .XLSX file containing 13 columns but only need columns 1 and 5.  I can export to tab delimited .TXT with only the two columns needed and it works fine, but I would like to avoid converting from the original file as it is regularly updated and others may be running this file.
Must be TEMP TABLE and must be XLSX.  The temp table will JOINed in a subsequent query.

I have the following query:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE office AS
(SELECT zip_code, DISPATCH_LEVEL
FROM EXTERNAL 'file.xlsx'
        (zip_code VARCHAR(10), DISPATCH_LEVEL VARCHAR(100))
        USING (REMOTESOURCE 'ODBC' DELIMITER '\t'));
```

I get the following error block:

> ERROR [HY008] Operation canceled
>   
> ERROR [01000] Unable to write nzlog/bad files 
>   
> ERROR [01000] Unable to write nzlog/bad files
>   
> ERROR [HY000] ERROR:  External Table : count of bad input rows reached maxerrors limit

Comment: I believe the part `Unable to write nzlog/bad files ` means "there was an error, and the logging of the error details failed." In other words, it is an error in the error handler. I get this because in Windows 10 the process by default does not have write permissions to c:\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Netezza external tables simply do not directly support XLSX files.  They require character delimited files, fixed length files, or internal/native format files.